# Debugging react native application in offline mode

Tags: debugging, react-native, offline

I'm trying to add some offline support for my app, but debugging the app with my emulator in airplane mode seems to be a giant pain. Every time I reload the app without a connection I am met with this:

[image]

So, in essence, I would like to have the app think it does not have a connection, but maintain the connection to my development server. Is that possible?

Comment: what about using `localhost` or `127.0.0.1`? The problem is `10.0.3.2` is being provided by your router so when you are on offline (or without connection), who is going to route that ip? Other option could be adding in your host (c:\C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc) a traduction for your IP, something like this: `10.0.3.2  127.0.0.1`. Of course you have to change your devs settings in your emulator

Comment: You are correct sir! The usual Genymotion localhost 10.0.3.2 does not work, but setting the debug host to 127.0.0.1 did the trick.  Thanks :)

Comment: I will post the answer so it will help to others too. Will you vote it up and accept it pls? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The problem is `10.0.3.2` is being provided by your router so when you are on offline (or without connection), who is going to route that ip?

One option to solve this problem is to use `localhost` or `127.0.0.1` as Debug Server.

Other option could be adding in your host (c:\C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc) a traduction for your IP, something like this:

```
10.0.3.2   127.0.0.1
```

Of course you have to change your devs settings in your emulator

Comment: "Of course you have to change your devs settings in your emulator" - which settings exactly?

Comment: From [Official Docs](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/running-on-device.html), Method 2 explains exactly how to do that.